# ICEfaces JSF Beans and Spring Beans, what VariableResolver?

Tags: spring, jsf, icefaces

I'm trying to understand the best way to use Spring (for dependency injection) with ICEfaces (Spring 3, ICEfaces 1.8.2, JSF RI 1.1).
Regarding the [Spring reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html#jsf), there are several possibilities to handle EL resolutions of beans:

If I use SpringBeanVariableResolver (which look best at first sight):

- Beans that are refered in an EL-Expression will be managed by Spring
- BUT the missing "extended request"-scope of Spring will cause problems, won't it?

If the DelegatingVariableResolver is used:

- Beans that are refered in an EL-Expression will be managed by JSF
- I need to define the EL-aware beans in faces-config.xml, which means I'm restraint to the limited options (e.g. no constructor DI).
- Bean declarations are scattered across different files

Is this correct? Any suggestions? Hints? Best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up in mixing common JSF DI with Spring DI. That means that I inject Spring beans as JSF managed properties.